# The array count returns wrong answer in php

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

This is my php code:

```
$allids_arr = $_REQUEST['allids'];
print_r($allids_arr);
echo $arr_count = count($allids_arr);
```

The array printed like this:

```
Array (
     [0] => 26 
     [1] => 27 
     [2] => 28 
     [3] => 29 
     [4] => 30 
     [5] => 31 
     [6] => 32 
     [7] => 33 
)
```

But the count display as `1`.

But the correct answer is `8`.

What is the problem in my code?

EDIT:

The array was i created:
This is the code for my array creation:

```
$allids = array();
        $ikall = 0;
        foreach($alldata as $rwosall){
            $allids[$ikall] = $rwosall['journelmodel']['id'];
            $ikall++;
        }   
        $this->set('alldataids', $allids);
```

This is in my controller.And in my view page:

```
<input type="hidden" readonly="" id="allids" class="input1" name="allids" value="<?php print_r($alldataids);?>">
```

This value was i requested when form submitted.

Comment: Instead of echo $arr_count = count($allids_arr); just use echo count($allids_arr);

Comment: i already tested that but it return `1`...

Comment: try commenting out the print_r just in case. Also try adding print_r to $_REQUEST['allids'];. Test everything.

Comment: How is made your request? Can you write an example?

Comment: You must be doing something else in the code that you aren't showing us. Try putting `echo count($_REQUEST['allids']);` at the top of your script. Then put `$allids_arr = $_REQUEST['allids'];` right afterwards. Then put `echo count($allids_arr);` right after that. No reason that should not give you consistent output. Also please `print_r($_REQUEST)` to make sure you are doing that right.

Comment: @Kichu What exactly do you expect your `<input..>` field to do with output from `print_r($array)`. That doesn't look like it'll work.

Comment: Cthulthu is right, that form will submit a single string formatted to look like an array. You need to either pack/unpack that data using, for example, JSON, or pass it in multiple inputs, one value per input.

Comment: ok now i got my mistakes.........thank you for your comments....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all there are few mistakes in your code.

1. You assign array in hidden field using print_r function which is not an array.
2. When you submit the value and get the value using $_REQUEST which is treated as a string.It looks like array that is why count is returning 1.

Solution : 
1. You can assign value as comma separated
like "x,y,z"

Answer (score 0):

you need:

```
echo count($allids_arr);
```

or

```
$arr_count = count($allids_arr);
echo $arr_count;
```

:)

Comment: but I tried in my code to do a `$foo = array("hi", 2, 8); echo $c = count($foo);` and it does print 3

Comment: Actually his version should work as well. The return value from an assignment is the RHS.

Comment: @Kichu do `echo count($allids_arr, 1);` It will count recursively, in case some elements are nested deeper. Not sure

Comment: @Kichu are you sure you didn't do anything in between printing of the array and printing the count?  Can you somehow make it into 3 lines of self-contained code or so that will show this behavior?

Comment: i cant understand your suggestion...do you mean to dont write it in 3 line of code is it?

Comment: Then one more thing i used this cakephp 2,if there is any problem in cakephp

Answer (score 0):

`$_REQUEST`, by default, contains the contents of `$_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE.`

But it's only a default, which depends on variables_order ; and not sure you want to work with cookies.

If I had to choose, I would probably not use `$_REQUEST`, and I would choose `$_GET or $_POST` -- depending on what my application should do (i.e. one or the other, but not both) : generally speaking :

```
You should use `$_GET` when someone is requesting data from your application.
And you should use `$_POST` when someone is pushing (inserting or updating ; or deleting) data to your application.
```

Either way, there will not be much of a difference about performances : the difference will be negligible, compared to what the rest of your script will do.

Comment: This would not explain the inconsistency in his output.

Comment: print_r($allids_arr);
echo $arr_count = count($allids_arr); //this code work fine.there must be default in somewhere $_REQUEST.use print_r($_REQUEST);

Answer (score 0):

Try use this:

```
<?php
    $foo = $_REQUEST['foo'];
    print_r($foo);
    echo $arr_count = count($foo);
?>
```

with this query:

`sample.php?foo[]=test&foo[]=baz&foo[]=foo`

It return correct result:

```
Array ( [0] => test [1] => baz [2] => foo ) 3
```

...probably if you use the same name for array and params, work well.

hope this help.